# Trying to install dev kit for ruby in windows 7 but fails

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-7

I am trying to install the dev kit for ruby for the CommandT plugin for vim and I am hit with

```
C:\Users\Administrator>gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        The 'rdiscount' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

I have already run install devkit at shown below

```
C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb review
Based upon the settings in the 'config.yml' file generated
from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations,
DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies
when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:/Ruby193

C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] RubyGems override already in place for C:/Ruby193, skipping.
[WARN] DevKit helper library already exists for C:/Ruby193, skipping.
```

What could be possibly going wrong?

**Edit:** I tried

```
c:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install --force

Configures an MSYS/MinGW based Development Kit (DevKit) for
each of the Ruby installations on your Windows system. The
DevKit enables you to build many of the available native
C-based RubyGems that don't yet have a binary gem.

Usage: ruby dk.rb COMMAND

where COMMAND is one of:

  init     prepare DevKit for installation
  review   review DevKit install plan
  install  install required DevKit executables
```

uninstalled and installed again with a clean directory. But the error remains the same.

Answer (score 9):

On this lines:

```
C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] RubyGems override already in place for C:/Ruby193, skipping.
[WARN] DevKit helper library already exists for C:/Ruby193, skipping.
```

It's telling you that it didn't install the DevKit for Ruby because it already had a previous DevKit registered there.

It might be possible you relocated a previous installation of DevKit, in which case you need to perform `ruby dk.rb install --force` to override the RubyGems and DevKit helper script it previously skipped.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For which i get `c:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install --force

Configures an MSYS/MinGW based Development Kit (DevKit) for
each of the Ruby installations on your Windows system. The
DevKit enables you to build many of the available native
C-based RubyGems that don't yet have a binary gem.

Usage: ruby dk.rb COMMAND

where COMMAND is one of:

  init     prepare DevKit for installation
  review   review DevKit install plan
  install  install required DevKit executables
`

Comment: Seems to me you have an old version of RubyInstaller DevKit, `--force` option has been around for months: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/resources/devkit/dk.rb.erb#L35-37

Comment: BTW, please include which version of DevKit did you tried to install. For Ruby 1.9.3, you need the  latest one mentioned in RubyInstaller downloads page: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

Comment: I assumes its DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe. Let me try with that.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. But my original intention was to install the commandT plugin for windows and I am not hit with `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postp
one'`

Comment: `c:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

c:\devkit>gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
Fetching: rdiscount-1.6.8.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rdiscount-1.6.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rdiscount-1.6.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for rdiscount-1.6.8...`

Comment: @QuintinPar I have no knowledge about commandT plugin, so can't comment/fix/whatever about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ruby dk.rb install, however, as suggested with the --force option it has successfully installed my devkit which in turn had resolved a gem install failure I was getting with JSON 1.4.6 gem.